# Dynamic list of user-mode dlls in windows

Tags: windows

I want to know which DLL is loaded/unloaded in which process (globally).
The purpose is to find a process loading and unloading DLLs on the fly.
I use following breakpoints in windbg (kd), but nothing found!

`bp kernel32!LoadlibraryA "da poi(esp+4);g"
 bp kernel32!LoadlibraryW "du poi(esp+4);g"`

any user/kernel mode ida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [`FLG_SHOW_LDR_SNAPS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556886(v=vs.85).aspx) in [GFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549557(v=vs.85).aspx) to get DLL loading and unloading notifications in WinDbg or [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896647.aspx) for all processes on the system.

Comment: It was useful thanx! when I set the flag and for example right click on task-bar, it doesn't show any loaded dll. but I'm sure that "browselc.dll" is loading each time I do it ( using break on loadlibrary )

Comment: That's because the DLL was already loaded before you right-clicked on the taskbar.

Comment: Got it! So it meanse FLG_SHOW_LDR_SNAPS shows real loadings only and bp on Loadlibrary shows both load and get handle!